# How do I set the input value in Angular 8?

Tags: angular, forms, input, angular8, ngmodel

I am building an invoice feature inspired from [this site](https://codepen.io/Jir/pen/bJJvJZ) and I want the first two lines of the invoice to be pre-filled with: 'Hours worked'  & 'Kilometers travelled'. The example code of the mentioned site is using the first version of Angularjs so I need to transform that into Angular 2+, so i changed `ng-model="items.description"` into `[(ngModel)]="items.description"`

In my invoice.component.ts I have declared this field:

```
  items:[
{ qty: 1, description: 'Hours worked', cost: 500 },
{ qty: 1, description: 'Kilometres traveled', cost: 4500 }
```

];
This is the full code block :

```
<div class="row invoice-item" *ngFor="let item of items" ng-animate="'slide-down'">
    <div class="col-xs-1 remove-item-container">
      <a href ng-hide="printMode" ng-click="removeItem(item)" class="btn btn-danger">[X]</a>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 input-container">
      <input [(ngModel)]="items.description" placeholder="description" >
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 input-container">
      <input ng-model="item.qty" value="1" size="4" ng-required ng-validate="integer" placeholder="Quantity" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 input-container">
      <input ng-model="item.cost" value="0.00" ng-required ng-validate="number" size="6" placeholder="Cost" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-2 text-right input-container">
      <!-- {{item.cost * item.qty | currency: currencySymbol}} -->
    </div>
  </div>
```

However, the lines are blank. What am I doing wrong?

(i know the rest of the code is still using Angularjs code, but that is not relevant right now)

Comment: You only defined a type for `items`, you didn't actually assign any value to it. Note the difference between `:` and `=`.

Comment: Also in the ngModel directive you should reference `item`, not `items`.

Comment: 'You only defined a type for items, you didn't actually assign any value to it. Note the difference between : and =' this did the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as **@Ingo Burk** mentioned above you just need to adjust the `"items"` from your code to `"item"`

> Your code

```
      <input [(ngModel)]="items.description" placeholder="description" >
...
```

> to this

```
      <input [(ngModel)]="item.description" placeholder="description" >
...
```

**Explain:** when you use `*ngFor="let item of items"`, the **"let item of items"** means let the **"item"** contains all the data of **"items"** so from that you just simply use the **"item"**. [(ngModel)] works as 2-way data binding which means the user can type in and see the output at the same time. I hope this will help you. Corrections are all welcome